# Who does Gurney Halleck work for when he is harvesting spice and attacked by Fremen led by Paul

Tags: plot-explanation, dune-part-two

In ***Dune Part 2***, Paul has led several raids against spice harvesters owned by the house of Harkonnen, who have better equipped soliders and aircrafts as guards.

When Gurney Halleck is attacked by Paul's raiding party, Gurney is working with a spice harvesting crew as well, but he and his crew are less protected and less well-equipped. Who are the crew Gurney Halleck is working with?

Comment: He literally explains in the movie that he's smuggling spice and that he's doing good business due to Paul sabotaging the official spice supply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [source novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)), after the death of the Duke Atreides and his son, Halleck and the small number of Atreides troops that escaped the Sardaukar made their way into the desert, where they teamed up with the smuggler Tuek.

> “So you’re the great Gurney Halleck,” the man said.
> Halleck stood staring across the round cavern office at the smuggler seated behind a metal desk. The man wore Fremen robes and had the half-tint blue eyes that told of off-planet foods in his diet. The office duplicated a space frigate’s master control center—communications and viewscreens along a thirty-degree arc of wall, remote arming and firing banks adjoining, and the desk formed as a wall projection—part of the remaining curve.
> “I am Staban Tuek, son of Esmar Tuek,” the smuggler said.
> “Then you’re the one I owe thanks for the help we’ve received,” Halleck said.

By the point that Paul catches up with him again, most of the survivors have moved off-world, but a small number, Halleck included, have stayed in the hopes of one day getting their revenge on the Harkonnen.

> “That’s a wager you’d win,” Paul said. He looked down at the men being disarmed. “Are there any more of my father’s men among your crew?”
> “None. We’re spread thin. There’re a few among the free traders. Most have spent their profits to leave this place.”
> “But you stayed.”
> “I stayed.”
> “Because Rabban is here,” Paul said.
> “I thought I had nothing left but revenge,” Gurney said.